# Mysql subquery return multiple row

Tags: mysql

I have two tables,

- `product`(product_id,category_id)
- `product_options`(option_id,product_id)

I want to insert those product in `product_options` whose `category_id` = `%%`

any suggestion would be appreciated

here is my query:

```
select (select product_id 
from oc_product 
where oc_product.product_id = oc_product_option.product_id) as product_id,
15 as option_id, '' as value,   
0 as required 
from oc_product_option 
inner join oc_product_to_category c 
on oc_product_option.product_id = c.product_id 
where c.category_id = 98
```

i give 4 records but i want all product which `category_id = 98`, as i know i have many product whose `category_id = 98`

Comment: illustrate your needs using some sample of data source and expected result set

Comment: here is my query   

 select 
  (select product_id from oc_product where oc_product.product_id = oc_product_option.product_id) as product_id, 
  15 as option_id, 
  '' as value, 
  0 as required 
 from oc_product_option 
 inner join oc_product_to_category c 
 on oc_product_option.product_id = c.product_id 
 where c.category_id = 98 
 
i give 4 records but i want all product which category_id = 98, 
as i know i have many product whose category_id = 98

Comment: your query is weird, and I didn't ask you for the query, I did ask for several records for ech of your 2 tables, and expected result set you need to get

Comment: Can't you just use a simple `JOIN`? Why do you need a subquery?

Comment: The question says you want to insert the products? Where do you want to insert them?

Comment: What is the `oc_product_to_category` table? The first part of your question says that `category_id` is in the `product` table, is that wrong?

Comment: All the table names in the query different from what you said at the beginning of the question? Why do you have to make things more confusing that way?

Comment: this is product table  

| product_id | category_id |
 11   90
 12   90
 13   90
 14   98
 15   98
 
this is product_option table

| product_option_id | product_id |
   auto increment    1
   auto increment    2
   auto increment    3
   auto increment    4
   auto increment    5
   
now i just want to insert 14,15 products in product_option table whose category_id = 98

Comment: There's no formatting in comments, update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be inserting into the `oc_product_option` table, not joining with it. That will only return products that already have options, not all the products in the category.

```
INSERT INTO oc_product_option (product_id, option_id, value, required)
SELECT p.product_id, 15 AS option_id, '' AS value, 0 AS required
FROM oc_product AS p
JOIN oc_product_to_category AS c ON o.product_id = c.product_id
WHERE c.category_id = 98
```

Actually, there isn't even any reason to join with `oc_product`, since you're not using anything from that table. You can just do:

```
INSERT INTO oc_product_option (product_id, option_id, value, required)
SELECT product_id, 15 AS option_id, '' AS value, 0 AS required
FROM oc_product_to_category
WHERE category_id = 98
```

Comment: dear Barmar,  i already made this query but it gives just 4 records but i know there are lot of products whose category_id = 98, why it gives just 4 records?

Comment: Since you join with `oc_product_option`, it only gives the products that have options.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about your requirement but I think this may help you.

```
SELECT 
    a.product_id, 
    15 AS option_id, 
    '' AS VALUE, 
    0 AS required 
FROM 
    oc_product a 
JOIN    
    oc_product_option b
ON  
    (a.product_id=b.product_id)
JOIN    
    oc_product_to_category c
ON  
    (a.product_id=c.product_id)
WHERE 
    c.category_id = 98;
```